# query for indexed key values that has the most references?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

We have a very big collection, with several indexes.

Since an `index` is basically a table with the indexed field as key, and a list of `ObjectID`s as value, we were wondering if we could somehow get the key that has the highest number of `Objects` it points to.

For example, if we have a collection:

```
{ _id: 1, a : 1, b : 1 },
{ _id: 2, a : 2, b : 2 },
{ _id: 3, a : 2, b : 3 },
{ _id: 4, a : 2, b : 4 },
{ _id: 5, a : 3, b : 4 },
{ _id: 6, a : 3, b : 4 },
{ _id: 7, a : 4, b : 4 }
```

Where there's an index of "`a`".
I assume there a table somewhere that looks like this:

```
index a:

"1" => [ 1 ], 
"2" => [ 2, 3, 4 ],
"3" => [ 5, 6 ],
"4" => [ 7 ]
```

In which case we'd like to somehow query for the index value with the longest list of objects - "`2`".

Is something like that possible in `MongoDB`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Actually, indexes don't have a list of document objectId's, just pointers to the data. To get document's objectId, system must go to the disk to read it. That's why, if you have a index what can answer to your query and you don't need `_id` in your result, remember always [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) {_id:0, key1:1, key2:1, keyX:1} so result can be returned from index and there is no need to go to the disk.